# Order in Kleene star operation?

Tags: regular-language, kleene-star

Every example I had seen with Kleene star operations over languages show the expansion in order so I was wondering, does Kleene star operation requires ordering in the language?

For example, given the language L = {a, b}

We know L* = {e, a, b, aa, ab, bb, aaa, aab, abb, ...} (where e = epsilon)

But what about elements like ba, bba, baa?

I know this could be a simple question, I am maybe missing something here.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: No, languages are sets, and sets do not have order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, elements like ba, bba are also included in Kleene closure and ordering also is required.
Example of L={a,b}
For length 0 we have e,
For length 1 we have {a,b}
For length 2 we have {aa,bb,ab,ba}
so on and so forth